# Loop through Each Line - tried PS and CMD

Tags: bash, powershell, loops, parsing

Good day, my problem is that my script only parse the first line of my list on each turn, the program in question has no batch support so it need to start for each line. It would be very nice if someone could even explain what i did wrong

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=1

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`cd /d J:\temp\2 ^& dir /p /b /s`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)
ECHO %var%

IF not exist "J:\temp\1\%var:~3%" (mkdir "J:\temp\1\%var:~3%")
RMDIR /s /q "J:\temp\1\%var:~3%\"

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%A in ( %var% ) DO (
SET count+=1
J:\temp\windows\comp.exe -o"J:\temp\1\%var:~3%" -cn -d10 -intense -brute -s125 -t-j "%var%" )
```

This also doesn't work

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a count = 1

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`cd /d J:\temp\2 ^& dir /p /b /s`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)
ECHO %var%

IF not exist "J:\temp\1\%var:~3%" (mkdir "J:\temp\1\%var:~3%")
rmdir /s /q "J:\temp\1\%var:~3%\"

for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%A in ( %var% ) do (
SET /a count+=1
echo !count!
J:\temp\windows\precomp.exe -o"J:\temp\1\%var:~3%" -cn -d10 -intense -brute -s125 -t-j "%var%" )
```

Tried Powershell, much smaller but no luck. powershell thinks the paths would be to long, but there are not

```
$file = (Get-ChildItem "J:\temp\2" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).fullname
$fout = (Get-ChildItem "J:\temp\2" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).fullname.Substring(10)

Robocopy "J:\temp\2" "J:\temp\1\" /S /E /ZB /DCOPY:T /SEC /COPYALL /XC /XO /XF *.*

Get-Content (Get-ChildItem "J:\temp\2" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).fullname | ForEach-Object {
J:\temp\windows\precomp.exe -o"J:\temp\1\$fout" -cn -d10 -intense -brute -s125 -t-j "$file"
}
```

Also Powerrshell: If I use Get-Content I get the error Access to the path is denied, or using Get-ChildItem show suddenly the wrong path and if manually matched it gives me the error ""ReadLines" with "1" argument(s)" So it does not parse it line by line anymore

```
$file = @(Get-ChildItem "J:\temp\2\" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).fullname
$fout = (Get-ChildItem "J:\temp\2\" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).fullname.Substring(10)

Robocopy "J:\temp\2" "J:\temp\1\" /S /E /ZB /DCOPY:T /SEC /COPYALL /XC /XO /XF *.*

$arrayFromFile = @(Get-Content $file)
$arrayFromFout = @(Get-Content $fout)

foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("$arrayFromFile"))
{
       J:\temp\windows\precomp.exe -o"J:\temp\1\$_arrayFromFout" -cn -d10 -intense -brute -s125 -t-j "$_arrayFromFile"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works now:

```
Robocopy "J:\temp\2" "J:\temp\1\temp\2\" /E /ZB /DCOPY:A /SEC /COPYALL /XC /XO /XF *.*

(Get-ChildItem "J:\temp\2\" -Recurse -Attributes !D -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).fullname | Out-File -FilePath .\Process.txt

foreach($file in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\Process.txt"))
{       
    $path = "J:\temp\1" + $file.Substring(2)
    J:\temp\windows\precomp.exe -o"$path" -cn -d10 -intense -brute -s125 -t-j $file
}
```

It seems impossible without using a external file

Answer (score 0):

Dont understand what you do in your foreach loop at the end. You take all data from J:\temp\2, but do nothing with it. For use this data you must use $_ variable in foreach.

```
 Get-Content (Get-ChildItem "J:\temp\2" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).fullname | ForEach-Object {
    J:\temp\windows\precomp.exe -o"J:\temp\1\$fout" -cn -d10 -intense -brute -s125 -t-j "$file"
    }
```

Comment: sadly this doesn't help ether (maybe powershell is now fool proof but without _ I see no differents)

Comment: you are wrong understand piping. When you do `Get-Content` you get data from file then you pipe each data from one file(as object) to pipe, to get data now in foreach loop you must use variable $_ to access data from each file.

Comment: Oh okay I see, I tried this now, but all errors are still there. What should I do now?
I propably tried almost every combination in any order, with more or less escape sequences, and so much more, but nothing works. How hard can it be to pipe/parse 2 arrays? Next I will try Bash, may linux help me

Comment: i just dont under stand what is your input and what output your are wait. Parse 2 arrays is very easy.

Comment: Well, the application has input and ouput cli, but would only operate on one file per run, and would change the file name, if not specified, I need to parse two arrays for this to generate a separte folder with the same structure and modified files with the original name. (so I/O is only path and path\file.extension as string list)
Should be, if it works like advertised haha

Comment: forgot about separate, and app. Just answer what you need do, because
`$arrayFromFile = @(Get-Content $file)` - receive you data from all files in your folder
`$arrayFromFout = @(Get-Content $fout)` - receive nothing because it not found files , path is not full